# <typeparamref> to a parameter of another class in C# XML doc

Tags: c#

Is there a way to refer to the generic parameter of another class? I know I can do this with the current class using `<typeparamref>`.

One example would be when writing the documentation of an async methods. These return Task and people would commonly need to refer to TResult. Look at the "Return Value" on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, for instance. They used `<paramref>` which obviously didn't do the job.

```
    /// <returns>
    /// A task that represents the asynchronous create operation.
    /// The value of the <paramref name="TResult"/> parameter contains the number of documents created.
    /// </returns>
    public static async Task<int> CreateDocumentsAsync(string filename)
```

What shall I use instead of `<paramref>`?

Comment: A concrete example would make your question much more clear.  That method is not generic, so `typeparamref` does not apply.  If you have a method that returns a generic `Task` then you should have a generic type parameter on the method (or class).

Comment: My class is not generic, but I need to refer to the generic parameter of the `Task` class, which in this case is bound to `int`. How am I supposed to write this doc? What did they do wrong in the [Stream.ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doc?

Comment: Why do you need to?  The return value is a `Task<int>` which can be documented using `returns`.  `typeparamref` is for documenting generic parameters of the method/class, not the return type.

Comment: It seems to be the right way to document the method, judging by the way it was written in the Stream class.

Comment: The example with the `Stream` class in mscorlib (your last comment) does seem strange. I do not think even _they_ got the reference correct. You can see their doc (in some version at least) in [/csharpfritz/dotnet-docs/blob/master/xml/System.IO/Stream.xml](https://github.com/csharpfritz/dotnet-docs/blob/master/xml/System.IO/Stream.xml) (search for `paramref name="TResult"` in that page). It does not seem correct. On doc pages [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813.aspx) and [Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync), `TResult` is no link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, so I'll post a couple of examples that may help you in regards to generics with the XML documentation.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="obj"></param>
private void IDoSomething<T>(T obj)
{

}

/// <summary>
/// See type <see cref="T:My.Namespace.MyObject"/>
/// </summary>
private MyObject MyObj;

public class MyObject
{

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this show the type itself? I need the _generic parameter_ of the type. So I want something which will print "TResult" to the user when I refer to the generic parameter of the `Task<TResult>` class.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible (and the example with `System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync` seems to be an example of an invalid reference, see my comment to the question above).

*The rest of this post is not an answer to your question but a suggestion for a more correct documentation:*

In your concrete example, you could refer to the `Result` property inside `Task<>` instead of the impossible reference to the type parameter `TResult` itself. That is:

```
/// <returns>
/// The value of the <see cref="Task{_}.Result" /> property contains ...
/// </returns>
public static async Task<int> CreateDocumentsAsync(string filename)
```

If you do not like the `_` hack above, you can do:

```
/// <returns>
/// The value of the <see cref="Task{Int32}.Result" /> property contains ...
/// </returns>
public static async Task<int> CreateDocumentsAsync(string filename)
```

Of course, you can refer to `int` with `<see cref="Int32" />`.